# summarize dates from a list of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table having an id column and validity start and end date columns. 
There are multiple validity date ranges are available for each id.

I want to minimize the records and make one row for each set of sequential dates wherever possible.

```
    declare @tbl table (cid int, st_date int, end_date int )


    insert into @tbl  (cid, st_date,end_date)  
    values (1,20190110,20190111),  
    (1,20190111,20190117), 
    (1,20190117,20190123), 
    (2,20190101,20190117), 
    (2,20190119,20190123),
    (2,20190123,20190127)
```

**output required :**

```
cid    st_date      end_date

  1    20190110     20190123

  2    20190101     20190117

  2    20190119     20190127
```

Comment: For starters I would strongly suggest using the date datatype for storing dates instead of ints. Then I would suggest checking out this article which explains how to group islands on contiguous data like this. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/group-islands-of-contiguous-dates-sql-spackle

Comment: Please use proper data type.  Using int or varchar as a type for date column will give you nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  But it is dealing with (potentially) overlapping intervals.  For a general solution I recommend:

```
select cid, min(st_date) as st_date, max(end_date) as end_date
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when max_prev_ed >= st_date then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by cid order by st_date) as grp
      from (select t.*, max(end_date) over (partition by cid order by st_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as max_prev_ed
            from @tbl t
           ) t
     ) t
group by cid, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62a60b6f4121d97075f71df55194fdd7) is a db<>fiddle.

This is a robust solution for situations such as:

- Overlaps of more than one day.
- Full inclusion of one interval within another.

Answer (score 0):

For each cid you'll generate the earliest start date, and latest end date.

```
SELECT cid, MIN(st_date) as st_date, MAX(end_date) as end_date
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY cid
```

Comment: No, Only where dates are in sequence for cid 1 it will work fine but for cid 2 there is validity gap of one day. I edited the example please see.

Comment: I'll keep working on this for a little bit, but you've basically ran into the "Gaps and Islands" problem. There isn't an easy solution to it, but I'd recommend [reading some articles](https://www.sqlshack.com/data-boundaries-finding-gaps-islands-and-more/) to help understand what's going on and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I found no other option but using CURSOR. You can now check the new Output listed below with your new provided data. To me, Output seems correct.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (cid INT, st_date INT, end_date INT )
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (cid INT, st_date INT, end_date INT, gid INT )

DECLARE @gid INT
SET @gid = 1

INSERT INTO @tbl (cid, st_date,end_date) 
VALUES 
(1,20190110,20190111), 
(1,20190111,20190117), 
(1,20190117,20190123), 
(2,20190101,20190117), 
(2,20190119,20190123), 
(2,20190123,20190127), 
(2,20190201,20190205), 
(2,20190205,20190210)

DECLARE @cid INT, @st_date INT, @end_date INT,@B_cid INT,@B_st_date INT

DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT A.cid,A.st_date,A.end_date,B.cid B_cid,B.st_date B_st_date
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CID,st_date,end_date) RN,* 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT CID,CONVERT(varchar, st_date, 23) st_date,CONVERT(varchar, end_date, 23) end_date FROM @tbl
    )X
)A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CID,st_date,end_date)-1 RN,* 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT CID,CONVERT(varchar, st_date, 23) st_date,CONVERT(varchar, end_date, 23) end_date FROM @tbl
    )Y
)B
ON A.RN = B.RN
ORDER BY 1,2

OPEN vendor_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
INTO @cid, @st_date,@end_date,@B_cid,@B_st_date  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

    IF  (@cid = @B_cid) AND (@end_date = @B_st_date)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @tmp (cid, st_date,end_date,gid) 
        VALUES 
        (@cid,@st_date,@end_date,@gid)

    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tmp (cid, st_date,end_date,gid) 
        VALUES 
        (@cid,@st_date,@end_date,@gid)

        SET @gid = @gid +1
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
    INTO @cid, @st_date,@end_date,@B_cid,@B_st_date   
END   
CLOSE vendor_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor

SELECT cid,
MIN(st_date) st_date,
MAX(end_date) end_date
FROM @tmp
GROUP BY cid,gid
```

New Output is-

```
cid st_date     end_date
1   20190110    20190123
2   20190101    20190117
2   20190119    20190127
2   20190201    20190210
```

Comment: Try this sample value instead, `INSERT INTO @tbl  (cid, st_date,end_date)  
VALUES (1,20190110,20190111), (1,20190111,20190117), (1,20190117,20190123), (2,20190101,20190117), (2,20190119,20190123), (2,20190123,20190127), (2,20190201,20190205), (2,20190205,20190210)`

Comment: New output added in the answer. Please check.

Comment: Some problem detected. Lets check I can handle or not.

Comment: Scripts changed with using CURSOR

Comment: This may produce the desired results but a cursor is a very inefficient method here. The performance is going to tank very quickly. Cursors should be avoided when set based options are available.

Comment: Of course CURSOR should be avoided if there other options available. But still, its a solution.